How to detect programmatically if two Globs intersect or not in Node.js?
In below array, the first glob is a subset of the second one:
[
  "HomePage/03-LocalDevelopmentBuild/public/**/*.@(js)",
  "HomePage/03-LocalDevelopmentBuild/**/*.@(js)"
]

But how can we detect it programmatically? AFAIK, the "minimatch" compares only the file path or directory path with the glob, not 2 globs.

I think you'd have to write an algorithm to do that by hand.

theoretical CS can help here. the question amounts to determining if one language A is a subset of the other B. -- to represent those languages, you'd want to use two automata, one automaton that recognizes each language. -- you'd build such an automaton from the glob expression directly, or by way of a regex from the glob. -- the subset test involves building the complement automaton B̅ for the suspected superset language, then intersecting both automata A ∩ B̅, and testing if the intersection is empty. if it's empty, then A ⊆ B.

the implementation for all that theoretical CS is rather involved and requires some study to understand to a degree that you can prove its correctness. from just seeing the code, one wouldn't understand why all those constructions are necessary.

As you found out, minimatch is not a good match for this task. Instead, we will have to create the algorithm ourselves (this allows for greater time efficiency when running the code since it is only handling strings). First, we have to separate the globs into the main path and the part with asterisks. We will call them path and juice, respectively:
function splitGlobs(glob) {
    let glob_arr = glob.split("*");
    let globPath = glob_arr[0];
    let globJuice = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < glob_arr.length; i++) {
        if (i != 0) {
            globJuice += "*" + glob_arr[i];
        }
    }
    return { path: globPath, juice: globJuice };
}

Now, we will have to input our globs and separate them using splitGlobs():
const globs = [
    "HomePage/03-LocalDevelopmentBuild/**/*.@(js)",
    "HomePage/03-LocalDevelopmentBuild/public/**/*.@(js)",
];

let glob0 = splitGlobs(globs[0]);
let glob1 = splitGlobs(globs[1]);

And now, for the main logic of the algorithm, we just have to check if one is or is not a subset of the other:
if (glob0.juice != glob1.juice) {
    console.log(
        `${globs[0]} and ${globs[1]} are not subsets -- they do not target the same file type.`,
    );
} else if (glob0.path.includes(glob1.path)) {
    console.log(`${globs[0]} is a subset of ${globs[1]}.`);
} else if (glob1.path.includes(glob0.path)) {
    console.log(`${globs[1]} is a subset of ${globs[0]}.`);
} else {
    console.log(
        `${globs[0]} and ${globs[1]} target the same file type, yet they are not subsets.`,
    );
}

Executing all the code yields

HomePage/03-LocalDevelopmentBuild/public/**/*.@(js) is a subset of HomePage/03-LocalDevelopmentBuild/**/*.@(js).

as expected. Now it is up to you to change the dummy text for real functionalities!
Hope this helped! And may the code be with you...

It is probably faster to just find what files match using the glob package and then finding the intersection of the resulting arrays. As of Node.js v22.0.0 you can also use glob directly from the node:fs module.
const filesA = glob.sync(globA)
const filesB = glob.sync(globB)
const intersection = filesA.filter(file => filesB.includes(file))
const hasIntersection = intersection.length > 0

I know this is not what you asked, but may get you what you’re ultimately after in a simpler and possibly more efficient way.
Here’s a similar question from SO showing the effort involved in the general case: Algorithm to find out whether the matches for two Glob patterns (or Regular Expressions) intersect.
